# AnyLogic and Alpyne library: Any issue with the Resource block?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, anylogic

I am trying to develop a simulation model in which actions are performed by an intelligent agent, through Reinforcement Learning, namely using the Alpyne library. After checking the sample examples that come with the library, I developed a simple model that worked fine. However, after adding other blocks to my model, the python code starts to freeze and return a "fresh status" that does not allow the execution to conclude. After a while, I was able to identify that the only block that was causing this issue was the Resource, so I replaced it with other workarounds. The model now works with this workaround, however, I would like to know what would be causing this? Is there something I have to do to be able to use the Resource block?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue. I don´t know what causes it, but i created an issue on GitHub, if you'd like to stay informed about it :)(https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/Alpyne/issues/18)